# MySQL Filtered Join

Tags: mysql, left-join

This seems like it would work, but telling to show records whose value is NOT zero, all seems to be telling it to not show records whose value is NULL. (that is records that are not in tableB). Seems 0 is equal to NULL in mysql. How do get the result I'm looking for?

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name, CategoryID
FROM sockcategory 
LEFT JOIN sockcategoryparentxref ON 
sockcategory.CategoryID = sockcategoryparentxref.Category_ID 
WHERE CategoryParentID !=0;
```

Schema / Sample Data

Table `sockcategory`:

```
+-----------+------------+
|   Name    | CategoryID |
+-----------+------------+
| Red       |          1 |
| Blue      |          2 |
| Green     |          3 |
| Colors    |          4 |
| Wholesale |          5 |
+-----------+------------+
```

Table `sockcategoryparentxref`:

```
+-------------+------------------+
| Category_ID | CategoryParentID |
+-------------+------------------+
|           1 |                4 |
|           2 |                4 |
|           3 |                4 |
|           4 |                0 |
+-------------+------------------+
```

Desired output:

```
+-----------+------------+
|   Name    | CategoryID |
+-----------+------------+
| Red       |          1 |
| Blue      |          2 |
| Green     |          3 |
| Wholesale |          5 |
+-----------+------------+
```

Comment: Could you perhaps provide a sample schema and desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `Name`, `CategoryID`
FROM `sockcategory` 
LEFT JOIN `sockcategoryparentxref`
    ON `sockcategory`.`CategoryID` = `sockcategoryparentxref`.`Category_ID`
    AND `CategoryParentID` <> 0;
```

Comment: that's it! I didn't know you could add additional conditions on the join.

Comment: @danjfoley - Sure you can, it's super-useful at times. Glad to have helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to compare `WHERE CategoryParentID IS NULL` rather like below assuming that `CategoryParentID` belongs to `sockcategoryparentxref` table.

```
select DISTINCT s.Name,
s.CategoryID 
FROM sockcategory s
LEFT JOIN sockcategoryparentxref so ON 
s.CategoryID = so.Category_ID 
WHERE so.CategoryParentID IS NULL;
```

If not, then consider moving the condition to `JOIN ON` clause

```
select DISTINCT s.Name,
s.CategoryID 
FROM sockcategory s
LEFT JOIN sockcategoryparentxref so ON 
s.CategoryID = so.Category_ID 
AND so.CategoryParentID <> 0;
```

Comment: your second answer is exactly what i'm looking for, but i'm going to give to the other answer, that just has that, to be less confusing and more concise to those looking for the same answer. I didn't realize you could put more then one condition on a join.